# How to store trip itinerary data into DynamoDB?

Tags: database, database-design, amazon-dynamodb, schema, data-modeling

I am trying to figure out the best way to store trip itinerary data into DynamoDB. Just for your info, my code is written in Python3 and I am using Boto3 to interact with DynamoDB.

After researching on this resource - https://schema.org/Trip, this is what I think would be the data classes of the objects.

```
from marshmallow_dataclass import dataclass
from typing import List, Optional


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Itinerary:
    id: str
    startTime: int
    endTime: int
    dayTripId: str
    placeName: str
    placeCategory: str
    estimatedCost: float


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class DayTrip:
    id: str
    day: str
    parentTripId: str
    date: Optional[str]
    itinerary: List[Itinerary]


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class UserTrip:
    tripId: str
    userId: str
    tripName: str
    subTrip: List[DayTrip]
```

Essentially, the structure is as follows:

- A person can have many `UserTrip`s
- A `UserTrip` can consist of one day or multiple day of `DayTrip`, e.g. Day 1, Day 2, Day 3
- A `DayTrip` can have one or multiple places to visit (`Itinerary`)
- An `Itinerary` is the lowest level that describes the place to visit

It wouldn't be good to store the `UserTrip` as is, with nested JSON structure consisting of `DayTrip`, then `Itinerary`, right? It would mean that the `subTrip` attribute of a particular `UserTrip` will be a huge chuck of JSON. So I think everyone here would agree this is a no, no. Is that correct?

Another alternative that I could think of was to store only the id of each entity. What I mean by this is, for example, a `UserTrip` will have its `subTrip` attribute containing a list of the `DayTrip` `id`. This means there will be another table to store `DayTrip` items and we can connect it to the corresponding `UserTrip` via the `parentTripId` attribute. And so on for the list of `Itinerary`.

Using this approach, I will have 3 x tables as follows:

- user-trip-table to store `UserTrip` where `subTrip` will contain the list of `DayTrip.id`s
- user-day-trip-table to store `DayTrip` where `itinerary` will contain the list of `Itinerary.id`s. The `parentTripId` will enable the mapping back to the original `UserTrip`
- user-itinerary-table to store `Itinerary` where it can be mapped back to the original `DayTrip` via `dayTripId` attribute.

I am not sure if this is a good practice as there will be a lot of lookups happening and asynchronous operations are not possible here. This is because, to fetch the `Itinerary`, I need to wait for the completion of `GetItem` operation to get `UserTrip`, then, I will have the ids of the `DayTrip` and then, I will do another `GetItem` to fetch the `DayTrip`, then, finally, another `GetItem` to fetch the `Itinerary`.

Could the community here suggest a better, simpler solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the data structure, I don't see an absolute need for `DayTrip`, as you can get all that data from `Itinerary`. So in `UserTrip` I would keep a list of Itineraries instead of a list of DayTrips.

> It wouldn't be good to store the UserTrip as is, with nested JSON
>   structure consisting of DayTrip, then Itinerary, right? It would mean
>   that the subTrip attribute of a particular UserTrip will be a huge
>   chuck of JSON. So I think everyone here would agree this is a no, no.
>   Is that correct?

Actually this [is recommended in NoSQL databases](https://youtu.be/jzeKPKpucS0?t=510), to have all data denormalised/embedded in the object. You use more storage, but avoid joins/processing. But keep in mind DynamoDB's item size limitation (currently 400KB).

In general, in NoSQL, you need to create your schema based on the queries you will need. For example in your case, you want to fetch all Itineraries of a UserTrip. Simply add `userTripId` to the `Itinerary` table. Create a [GSI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) on `Itinerary` 
with `userTripId` as hash key so you can query it efficiently. This way you will get all itinerary objects of a user trip.

Comment: Interesting. I have been using DynamoDB but never spent time reading the fundamentals. :| Btw, what about the day in which the itinerary is in? Is it good to have the day attribute in each of the itinerary object instead of grouping them under a day attribute?

Comment: For the day I am thinking you can deduce it from `startTime` and/or `endTime`. If you need it for querying purposes, set is a `day` field in `Itinerary`.

Comment: Also no need to store `subTrip: List[DayTrip]` in `UserTrip`, you can get them by querying the Itinerary by `userTryId`

Comment: are you suggesting to have 2 x tables? one to store the `Itinerary` objects and another the `UserTrip` objects? So in the `UserTrip`, I don't even need to have the `subTrip` or `List[Itineraries]` anymore, because once I have the `tripId`, I can query both tables in parallel by `tripId`, given that I add `tripId` to `Itinerary` data class?

Comment: yes. You can even add the userId and tripName to every Itinerary. This way you will have only 1 table. But I guess the two tables is the best solution

Comment: interesting. never thought that this was a good approach until now. regarding the `day` attribute, the reason why is because the `startTime` and `endTime` do not have any day or date info, it only contains time, e.g. 9:00, 18:30. i know that each `Itinerary` can have `day`, but just wondering would it be more efficient to take `day` out and put it in `UserTrip`? e.g. day 1: itinerary 1, itinerary 2, itinerary 3 rather than each itinerary has `day` equals `day 1`?

Comment: I would go with the `day` in the `Itinerary` table

Comment: Do you mind giving a short explanation why you would go with that?

Comment: easier to manipulate new itineraries in a trip. Adding or removing will not require operations on a big list.